# How to use ngrx-schematics in an Ionic 4 project?

Tags: angular, ionic4, ngrx

I'm trying to use ngrx-schematics within an Ionic 4 project, but I can't seem to make it work.

Just started an Ionic 4 project and installed ngrx store, entity, effects and schematics. I also have globally installed angular-cli 8, although Ionic still uses version 7. I found on the web ways to make ngrx-schematics work with Ionic 3 by creating a `angular-cli.json` file with some configuration. I think that, since Angular 6, that file no longer exists on angular projects, so I didn't create it.

I ran the command `ng config schematics.colection @ngrx/schematics` so I could integrate angular schematics with ngrx schematics.
Unfortunately, it didn't work, because when I tried to create a store with the command `ng g store State --root --module app.module.ts` I get the following error: `Error: Schematic "store" not found in collection "@ionic/angular-toolkit".`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new way of adding schematics(here ngrx/schematics) would be `ng config cli.defaultCollection @ngrx/schematics`. Here is the [reference](https://ngrx.io/guide/schematics#default-schematics-collection)

Comment: After adding ngrx/schematics, ionic cli broke for creating new pages. I got the following error: Schematic "page" not found in collection "@ngrx/schematics".

Comment: Actually `@ngrx/schematics` by default extends `@schematics/angular`. It seems once you set it as default, you can use only schematics relevant to angular and ngrx.  Here is the [reference](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/schematics/collection.json#L2).

Comment: so if you want to use `@ionic/angular-toolkit`, you have to do this `ng g someCustomSchematics --collection someCustomCollection`(this is for angular. just change it for ionic). The thing is, you need to pass ionic collection name to it. There is [PR](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12157)  which tracks for multiple default collections.. check it out.